# Is there a way to lint event listener types in JS/TS?

Tags: javascript, eslint, tslint, typescript-eslint

I use eslint and tslint to help me avoid silly mistakes.

However, today, I made a mistake when declaring an event listener to catch uncaught promise rejections:

```
   window.addEventListener('unhandledRejection', debugError)
```

The correct type is `unhandledrejection`, not `unhandledRejection`.  I wasted a lot of time debugging this before I realized I had made a typo.  Given the prevelance of camelCase in JS, I fear I will make the same mistake again.

Is there some way to lint this against known event types?  I don't use any custom events in my app.

Comment: A potential work around that may be useful depending on the size of your codebase would be to create an enum for all event types. This way at least you don't have to worry about miscapitalizing it in one place and not another.